# pcregrep matching stop at 1st occurrence

Tags: regex, pcregrep

I am implementing a multiline search in UNIX using 'pcregrep'. I want the matching to stop at the 1st occurrence.

e.g. if i have below text in a file:

```
mynameishin
hahahain
internetin
fdhsufsdhuiain
djbssdvbsbsduiain
sduigsyubsuvasdyivsyifvasin
```

I want to print till the 1st occurrence of 'ain' after 'name'. So i need to print only:

```
mynameishin
hahahain
```

I am executing:

```
pcregrep -M 'name.*ain' *.txt
```

However I am getting the output as:

```
mynameishin
hahahain
internetin
fdhsufsdhuiain
djbssdvbsbsduiain
```

Answer (score 6):

```
pcregrep -M 'name.*?ain' *.txt
```

Make it non greedy!!!!!!!!!!!`.*` is greedy.it will consume all and stop at end.

Comment: @user3921984 do not forget to mark this correct if it workd for you.